# Transforms vs. Table triggers in SymmetricDS

Tags: symmetricds

In the source database we have a table, lets call it TableA. with primary key PK_TableA. This table has a dependent table in source database, lets call it TableB, via a FK - lets call it FK_TableA. 
We syncronize TableA from source database to target database, with same table names.
We do NOT syncronize TableB from source database to target database, but it exists in target database with the same name and has the same relation of dependence with TableA.

When a row is deleted from TableA in source database, TableB is updated by modifying all the rows with the deleted FK, setting FK_TableA column to null.
We intend to produce the same behaviour in target database without having to syncronize TableB.
So, on delete of a row from TableA in source database we:
1) want to update, to null, column FK_TableA from TableB in the target database, for the corresponding rows
2) delete the row from TableA in targert database

Is this possible?
What is the best mechanism? Transforms or Table Triggers (maybe with a Sync On Delete Condition)?
Can you please try to explain the way to do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Either a load filter or a load transform would work.  The load filter is probably simpler for this case.  Use sym_load_filter to configure a "before write" BeanShell script that does this:

```
if (data.getDataEventType().name().equals("DELETE")) {
   context.findTransaction().execute("update tableb set fk_tablea = null " +
      "where fk_tablea = " + OLD_FK_TABLEA);
}
return true;
```

The script checks that it's a DELETE statement, then it will run the SQL you need.  The values for the table columns on the current row are available as upper case variables.  The script returns true so the original delete will also run.

See https://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.10/html/user-guide.html#_load_filters for more details on how to use load filters.